# Collection of exact string matching algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, strings

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110167/collection-of-exact-string-matching-algorithms-in-java-follow-up).)

I have this small collection of exact string matching algorithms:

1. [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm),
2. [Finite automaton matcher](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-set-5-efficient-constructtion-of-finite-automata/),
3. [Rabin-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm),
4. [Z algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/z-algorithm-linear-time-pattern-searching-algorithm/).

The main research question was comparing performance of all the algorithms in two different settings:

1. Input which degrades performance of the naïve string matcher (`String.indexOf`), where both the text and the pattern are of the format `aaaa...aab`,
2. Both text and the pattern are random.

---

The results are:

> ```
> [WORST CASE OF String.indexOf]
> String.indexOf in 6976 milliseconds.
> Knuth-Morris-Pratt matcher in 56 milliseconds.
> Finite automaton matcher in 98 milliseconds.
> Rabin-Karp matcher in 74 milliseconds.
> Z matcher in 89 milliseconds.
>
> [RANDOM STRINGS]
> [SEED: 1446895693075]
> String.indexOf in 238 milliseconds.
> Knuth-Morris-Pratt matcher in 303 milliseconds.
> Finite automaton matcher in 371 milliseconds.
> Rabin-Karp matcher in 909 milliseconds.
> Z matcher in 705 milliseconds.
> ```

---

**net.coderodde.string.matching.StringMatchers.java**:

```java
package net.coderodde.string.matching;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 * This class contains different string matching algorithms as static methods.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Nov 7, 2015)
 */
public final class StringMatchers {

    public static final int NOT_FOUND_INDEX = -1;

    public static final class KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher {

        /**
         * This static method implements the 
         * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm">
         * Knuth-Morris-Pratt</a> pattern matching algorithm that runs in time
         * {@code O(n + m)}, where {@code n} is the length of the text to search
         * and {@code m} is the length of the pattern to search.
         * 
         * @param text       the text to search in.
         * @param pattern    the pattern to search for.
         * @param startIndex the character index from which to start matching.
         * @return the smallest index no less than {@code startIndex} of the
         *         position where the pattern occurs if there is a match, or
         *         {@code NOT_FOUND_INDEX} if there is no match.
         */
        public static int match(String text, String pattern, int startIndex) {
            if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            }

            int n = text.length();
            int m = pattern.length();

            if (m > n) {
                return -1;
            }

            int[] prefixFunction = computePrefixFunction(pattern);
            int q = 0;

            for (int i = Math.max(0, startIndex); i < n; ++i) {
                while (q > 0 && pattern.charAt(q) != text.charAt(i)) {
                    q = prefixFunction[q - 1];
                }

                if (pattern.charAt(q) == text.charAt(i)) {
                    ++q;
                }

                if (q == m) {
                    return i - m + 1;
                }
            }

            return NOT_FOUND_INDEX;
        }

        public static int match(String text, String pattern) {
            return match(text, pattern, 0);
        }

        private static int[] computePrefixFunction(String pattern) {
            int m = pattern.length();
            int[] prefixFunction = new int[m];
            int k = 0;

            for (int q = 1; q < m; ++q) {
                while (k > 0 && pattern.charAt(k) != pattern.charAt(q)) {
                    k = prefixFunction[k - 1];
                }

                if (pattern.charAt(k) == pattern.charAt(q)) {
                    ++k;
                }

                prefixFunction[q] = k;
            }

            return prefixFunction;
        }
    }

    public static final class AutomatonMatcher {

        /**
         * This static method implements the algorithm for exact string matching
         * that constructs a finite automaton, and uses it in order to detect
         * a pattern. The running time is {@code n + sm}, where {@code n} is the
         * length of the text to search, {@code m} is the length of the pattern,
         * and {@code s} is the amount of distinct characters in the pattern.
         * 
         * @param text       the text to search in.
         * @param pattern    the pattern to search for.
         * @param startIndex the character index from which to start matching.
         * @return the smallest index no less than {@code startIndex} of the
         *         position where the pattern occurs if there is a match, or
         *         {@code NOT_FOUND_INDEX} if there is no match.
         */
        public static int match(String text, String pattern, int startIndex) {
            if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            }

            int n = text.length();
            Integer m = pattern.length();

            if (m > n) {
                return NOT_FOUND_INDEX;
            }

            TransitionFunction transitionFunction = 
                    computeTransitionFunction(pattern);

            Integer j = 0;

            for (int i = Math.max(0, startIndex); i < n; ++i) {
                if (j == null) {
                    j = 0;
                }

                j = transitionFunction.getState(j, text.charAt(i));

                if (m.equals(j)) {
                    return i - m + 1;
                }
            }

            return NOT_FOUND_INDEX;
        }

        public static int match(String text, String pattern) {
            return match(text, pattern, 0);
        }

        private static TransitionFunction 
        computeTransitionFunction(String pattern) {
            return new TransitionFunction(pattern);
        }

        private static final class TransitionFunction {

            private final Map<Character, Integer>[] function;

            TransitionFunction(String pattern) {
                int m = pattern.length();
                this.function = new HashMap[m + 1];

                Set<Character> filter = new HashSet(m);

                for (Character c : pattern.toCharArray()) {
                    filter.add(c);
                }

                int numberOfCharacters = filter.size();
                Character[] characterArray = new Character[numberOfCharacters];
                filter.toArray(characterArray);

                for (int i = 0; i < function.length; ++i) {
                    function[i] = new HashMap<>(numberOfCharacters);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCharacters; ++i) {
                    function[0].put(characterArray[i], 0);
                }

                function[0].put(pattern.charAt(0), 1);

                for (int i = 1, lps = 0; i <= m; ++i) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfCharacters; ++x) {
                        function[i].put(characterArray[x], 
                                        function[lps].get(characterArray[x]));
                    }


                    if (i < m) {
                        function[i].put(pattern.charAt(i), i + 1);
                        lps = function[lps].get(pattern.charAt(i));
                    }
                }
            }

            Integer getState(int currentState, char character) {
                return function[currentState].get(character);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Set<Character> alphabet = new TreeSet<>(function[0].keySet());
                Character[] array = new Character[alphabet.size()];
                alphabet.toArray(array);

                for (Map<Character, Integer> map : function) {
                    for (Character c : array) {
                        sb.append(map.get(c)).append(' ');
                    }

                    sb.append('\n');
                }

                return sb.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    public static final class RabinKarpMatcher {
        /**
         * This static method implements the Rabin-Karp algorithm for exact 
         * string matching: The worst case running time is {@code nm}, where 
         * {@code n} is the length of the text to search and {@code m} is the 
         * length of the pattern.
         * 
         * @param text       the text to search in.
         * @param pattern    the pattern to search for.
         * @param startIndex the character index from which to start matching.
         * @return the smallest index no less than {@code startIndex} of the
         *         position where the pattern occurs if there is a match, or
         *         {@code NOT_FOUND_INDEX} if there is no match.
         */
        public static int match(String text, String pattern, int startIndex) {
            int m = pattern.length();

            if (m == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            int n = text.length();
            startIndex = Math.max(0, startIndex);

            if (m + startIndex > n) {
                return NOT_FOUND_INDEX;
            }

            Set<Character> alphabet = new HashSet<>();

            for (char c : pattern.toCharArray()) {
                alphabet.add(c);
            }

            long d = alphabet.size();
            long q = 2;
            long h = intpow(d, m - 1) % q;

            long p = 0;
            long t = 0;

            // Beginning of preprocessing.
            for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                p = (d * p + (long)(pattern.charAt(i))) % q;
                t = (d * t + (long)(text.charAt(i + startIndex))) % q;
            }
            // End of preprocessing.

            // Beginning of matching.
            for (int s = startIndex; s <= n - m;  ++s) {
                if (p == t) {
                    if (hasMatch(pattern, text, s)) {
                        return s;
                    }
                }

                if (s < n - m) {
                    long save_t = t;
                    t = (d * (save_t - (long)(text.charAt(s)) * h) + 
                         (long)(text.charAt(s + m))) % q;

                    if (t < 0) {
                        t = (t + q);
                    }
                }
            }

            return NOT_FOUND_INDEX;
        }

        private static boolean hasMatch(String pattern, 
                                        String text, 
                                        int shift) {
            int m = pattern.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
                if (pattern.charAt(i) != text.charAt(i + shift)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static long intpow(long base, int exponent) {
            long ret = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < exponent; ++i) {
                ret *= base;
            }

            return ret;
        }

        public static int match(String text, String pattern) {
            return match(text, pattern, 0);
        }
    }

    public static final class ZMatcher {

        /**
         * This static method implements the Z-algorithm for exact string 
         * matching. The running time is {@code n + m}, where {@code n} is the
         * length of the text to search and {@code m} is the length of the 
         * pattern. The space complexity is linear.
         * 
         * @param text       the text to search in.
         * @param pattern    the pattern to search for.
         * @param startIndex the character index from which to start matching.
         * @return the smallest index no less than {@code startIndex} of the
         *         position where the pattern occurs if there is a match, or
         *         {@code NOT_FOUND_INDEX} if there is no match.
         */
        public static int match(String text, String pattern, int startIndex) {
            if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            }

            int n = text.length();
            int m = pattern.length();

            if (m > n) {
                return -1;
            }

            startIndex = Math.max(0, startIndex);

            if (startIndex != 0) {
                text = text.substring(startIndex);
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length() + 
                                                 pattern.length() + 1 -
                                                 startIndex);

            sb.append(pattern).append(Character.valueOf('\0')).append(text);
            // Do not create a new string from the StringBuilder, but rather
            // use the builder to access the data.
            int[] zArray = computeZArray(sb);

            for (int i = Math.max(0, startIndex); i < zArray.length; ++i) {
                if (zArray[i] == m) {
                    return i - m - 1 + startIndex;
                }
            }

            return NOT_FOUND_INDEX;
        }

        public static int match(String text, String pattern) {
            return match(text, pattern, 0);
        }

        private static int[] computeZArray(StringBuilder sb) {
            int n = sb.length();
            int[] ret = new int[n];

            int l = 0;
            int r = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
                if (i > r) {
                    l = i;
                    r = i;

                    while (r < n && sb.charAt(r - l) == sb.charAt(r)) {
                        ++r;
                    }

                    ret[i] = r - l;
                    --r;
                } else {
                    int k = i - l;

                    if (ret[k] < r - i + 1) {
                        ret[i] = ret[k];
                    } else {
                        l = i;

                        while (r < n && sb.charAt(r - l) == sb.charAt(r)) {
                            ++r;
                        }

                        ret[i] = r - l;
                        --r;
                    }
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

**PerformanceDemo.java**:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import net.coderodde.string.matching.StringMatchers;

public class PerformanceDemo {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        int N = 3_000_000;
        int M = 3000;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(N);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            sb.append('a');
        }

        String text = sb.append('b').toString();

        sb.delete(0, sb.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
            sb.append('a');
        }

        String pattern = sb.append('b').toString();

        System.out.println("[WORST CASE OF String.indexOf]");
        demo(text, pattern);

        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        text = getRandomText(random);
        pattern = getRandomPattern(random);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("[RANDOM STRINGS]");
        System.out.println("[SEED: " + seed + "]");

        demo(text, pattern);
    }

    private static String getRandomText(Random random) {
        int n = 10_000_000;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            sb.append('a' + random.nextInt(26));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String getRandomPattern(Random random) {
        int n = 1_000;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            sb.append('a' + random.nextInt(26));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void profile(BiFunction<String, String, Integer> matcher,
            String text,
            String pattern,
            int expectedIndex,
            String matcherName) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int index = matcher.apply(text, pattern);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (index != expectedIndex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    matcher.getClass() + " failed. Returned: " + index
                    + ", expected: " + expectedIndex);
        }

        System.out.println(matcherName + " in "
                + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds.");
    }

    private static void demo(String text, String pattern) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int expectedIndex = text.indexOf(pattern);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("String.indexOf in " + (endTime - startTime)
                + " milliseconds.");

        profile(StringMatchers.KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher::match,
                text,
                pattern,
                expectedIndex,
                "Knuth-Morris-Pratt matcher");

        profile(StringMatchers.AutomatonMatcher::match,
                text,
                pattern,
                expectedIndex,
                "Finite automaton matcher");

        profile(StringMatchers.RabinKarpMatcher::match,
                text,
                pattern,
                expectedIndex,
                "Rabin-Karp matcher");

        profile(StringMatchers.ZMatcher::match,
                text,
                pattern,
                expectedIndex,
                "Z matcher");
    }
}
```

**StringMatchersTest.java**:

```java
package net.coderodde.string.matching;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static net.coderodde.string.matching.StringMatchers.*;

public class StringMatchersTest {

    @Test
    public void testKnuthMorrisPrattMatcher() {
        assertEquals(-1, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(0,  KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aaaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(-1, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aaaa", "bb"));
        assertEquals(1,  KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("abbb", "bb"));
        assertEquals(2,  KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("abcc", "cc"));

        assertEquals(5, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aaaaaaab", "aab"));
        assertEquals(4, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("ababababaca", 
                                                      "ababaca"));

        assertTrue("".indexOf("") == KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("", ""));
        assertTrue("".indexOf("a") == KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("", "a"));
        assertTrue("a".indexOf("") == KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("a", ""));
        assertTrue("hello".indexOf("ello", -2) == 
                KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("hello", "ello", -2));

        assertEquals(-1, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 5));
        assertEquals(-1, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 4));
        assertEquals(3, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 3));
        assertEquals(3, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 2));
        assertEquals(3, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 1));
        assertEquals(0, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 0));
        assertEquals(0, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", -1));
        assertEquals(0, KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", -2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAutomatonMatcher() {
        assertEquals(0, AutomatonMatcher.match("acacaga", "acacaga"));
        assertEquals(-1, AutomatonMatcher.match("aaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(0,  AutomatonMatcher.match("aaaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(-1, AutomatonMatcher.match("aaaa", "bb"));
        assertEquals(1,  AutomatonMatcher.match("abbb", "bb"));
        assertEquals(2,  AutomatonMatcher.match("abcc", "cc"));

        assertEquals(5, AutomatonMatcher.match("aaaaaaab", "aab"));
        assertEquals(4, AutomatonMatcher.match("ababababaca", "ababaca"));

        assertTrue("".indexOf("") == AutomatonMatcher.match("", ""));
        assertTrue("".indexOf("a") == AutomatonMatcher.match("", "a"));
        assertTrue("a".indexOf("") == AutomatonMatcher.match("a", ""));
        assertTrue("hello".indexOf("ello", -2) == 
                AutomatonMatcher.match("hello", "ello", -2));

        assertEquals(-1, AutomatonMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 5));
        assertEquals(-1, AutomatonMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 4));
        assertEquals(3, AutomatonMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 3));
        assertEquals(3, AutomatonMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 2));
        assertEquals(3, AutomatonMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 1));
        assertEquals(0, AutomatonMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 0));
        assertEquals(0, AutomatonMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", -1));
        assertEquals(0, AutomatonMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", -2));
    }

    @Test
    public void testRabinKarpMatcher() {
        assertEquals(0, RabinKarpMatcher.match("acacaga", "acacaga"));
        assertEquals(-1, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(0,  RabinKarpMatcher.match("aaaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(-1, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aaaa", "bb"));
        assertEquals(1,  RabinKarpMatcher.match("abbb", "bb"));
        assertEquals(2,  RabinKarpMatcher.match("abcc", "cc"));

        assertEquals(5, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aaaaaaab", "aab"));
        assertEquals(4, RabinKarpMatcher.match("ababababaca", "ababaca"));

        assertTrue("".indexOf("") == RabinKarpMatcher.match("", ""));
        assertTrue("".indexOf("a") == RabinKarpMatcher.match("", "a"));
        assertTrue("a".indexOf("") == RabinKarpMatcher.match("a", ""));
        assertTrue("hello".indexOf("ello", -2) == 
                RabinKarpMatcher.match("hello", "ello", -2));

        assertEquals(-1, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 5));
        assertEquals(-1, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 4));
        assertEquals(3, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 3));
        assertEquals(3, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 2));
        assertEquals(3, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 1));
        assertEquals(0, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 0));
        assertEquals(0, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", -1));
        assertEquals(0, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", -2));
        assertEquals(6, RabinKarpMatcher.match("aaaaaaaab", "aab"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testZMatcher() {
        assertEquals(0, ZMatcher.match("acacaga", "acacaga"));
        assertEquals(-1, ZMatcher.match("aaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(0,  ZMatcher.match("aaaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(-1, ZMatcher.match("aaaa", "bb"));
        assertEquals(1,  ZMatcher.match("abbb", "bb"));
        assertEquals(2,  ZMatcher.match("abcc", "cc"));

        assertEquals(5, ZMatcher.match("aaaaaaab", "aab"));
        assertEquals(4, ZMatcher.match("ababababaca", "ababaca"));

        assertTrue("".indexOf("") == ZMatcher.match("", ""));
        assertTrue("".indexOf("a") == ZMatcher.match("", "a"));
        assertTrue("a".indexOf("") == ZMatcher.match("a", ""));
        assertTrue("hello".indexOf("ello", -2) == 
                ZMatcher.match("hello", "ello", -2));

        assertEquals(-1, ZMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 5));
        assertEquals(-1, ZMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 4));
        assertEquals(3, ZMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 3));
        assertEquals(3, ZMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 2));
        assertEquals(3, ZMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 1));
        assertEquals(0, ZMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", 0));
        assertEquals(0, ZMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", -1));
        assertEquals(0, ZMatcher.match("aabaab", "aab", -2));
        assertEquals(6, ZMatcher.match("aaaaaaaab", "aab"));
    }
}
```

As of this writing, all matchers pass the same set of tests, and they agree in the demonstration, so I guess there is not much to add to the correctness. However, the code is not quite cohesive, so I would like to hear about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Matcher implementations**

You group all these matchers in a `StringMatchers` class. Other than grouping the matchers together, this class adds no real benefit.
All macher's `match()` methods are static. Yet all have the same `match()` methods. This just aches to be refactored to all matchers implementing the same interface.

```
public interface StringMatcher {

    int NOT_FOUND_INDEX = -1;

    int match(String text, String pattern, int startIndex);

    default int match(String text, String pattern) {
        return match(text, pattern, 0);
    }
}
```

The `StringMatchers` class can still house the 4 implementations, but rather than exposing the implementation classes, we'll make the classes private and add factory methods to the `StringMatchers` class.

```
public final class StringMatchers {

    public static StringMatcher knuthMorrisPrattMatcher() {
        return new KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher();
    }

    public static StringMatcher automatonMatcher() {
        return new AutomatonMatcher();
    }

    public static StringMatcher rabinKarpMatcher() {
        return new RabinKarpMatcher();
    }

    public static StringMatcher zMatcher() {
        return new ZMatcher();
    }

    private static final class KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher implements StringMatcher { ... }

    private static final class AutomatonMatcher implements StringMatcher { ... }

    private static final class RabinKarpMatcher implements StringMatcher { ... }

    private static final class ZMatcher implements StringMatcher { ...}
}
```

Ultimately you could even refactor this to an `enum`.

In all algorithms you use single letter variable names. As a rule this is not done. For well documented algorithms it could be permissable if the published algorithm defines these variables. I've checked the `KnuthMorrisPrattMatcher`, and found that the referenced material uses different variable names. So either correct that, or use meaningful variable names. Otherwise, in 6 months time, even you will be scratching your head when reviewing this code.

**The StringMatchers test**

All StringMatcher implementations should pass the same tests. Since they now have a common interface, we can test against the interface.
We could make an abstract test class and 4 subclasses to test each implementation.

```
public abstract class StringMatchersTest {

    abstract StringMatcher getMatcherToTest();

    @Test
    public void testMatcher() {
        assertEquals(0, getMatcherToTest().match("acacaga", "acacaga"));
        assertEquals(-1, getMatcherToTest().match("aaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(0,  getMatcherToTest().match("aaaa", "aaaa"));
        assertEquals(-1, getMatcherToTest().match("aaaa", "bb"));
        assertEquals(1,  getMatcherToTest().match("abbb", "bb"));
        assertEquals(2,  getMatcherToTest().match("abcc", "cc"));

        assertEquals(5, getMatcherToTest().match("aaaaaaab", "aab"));
        assertEquals(4, getMatcherToTest().match("ababababaca", "ababaca"));

        assertTrue("".indexOf("") == getMatcherToTest().match("", ""));
        assertTrue("".indexOf("a") == getMatcherToTest().match("", "a"));
        assertTrue("a".indexOf("") == getMatcherToTest().match("a", ""));
        assertTrue("hello".indexOf("ello", -2) ==  getMatcherToTest().match("hello", "ello", -2));

        assertEquals(-1, getMatcherToTest().match("aabaab", "aab", 5));
        assertEquals(-1, getMatcherToTest().match("aabaab", "aab", 4));
        assertEquals(3, getMatcherToTest().match("aabaab", "aab", 3));
        assertEquals(3, getMatcherToTest().match("aabaab", "aab", 2));
        assertEquals(3, getMatcherToTest().match("aabaab", "aab", 1));
        assertEquals(0, getMatcherToTest().match("aabaab", "aab", 0));
        assertEquals(0, getMatcherToTest().match("aabaab", "aab", -1));
        assertEquals(0, getMatcherToTest().match("aabaab", "aab", -2));
    }

}

public class KnuthMorrisPrattMatcherTest extends StringMatchersTest {
    @Override
    StringMatcher getMatcherToTest() {
        return StringMatchers.knuthMorrisPrattMatcher();
    }
}
```

Or (even better) we can use the `Parameterized` Junit runner :

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class StringMatchersTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static List<Object[]> getParameters() {
        return asList(
                new Object[]{ StringMatchers.knuthMorrisPrattMatcher() },
                new Object[]{ StringMatchers.automatonMatcher() },
                new Object[]{ StringMatchers.rabinKarpMatcher() },
                new Object[]{ StringMatchers.zMatcher() }
        );
    }

    private final StringMatcher matcher;

    public StringMatchersTest(StringMatcher matcher) {
        this.matcher = matcher;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMatcher() { ... }
}
```

Either way, you'll want to make a separate test method for each assertion. That way it's immediately clear which specific test case fails.

**PerformanceDemo**

You measure elapsed time using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. [Use `System.nanoTime` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java).

Here as well, you can eliminate some repeated code by exploiting the fact that all implementations now implement a common interface. The `profile()` method can now accept `StringMatcher` as a parameter, rather than a `BiFunction`.

`getRandomText()` and `getRandomPattern()` are the same methods, once you make the desired length a parameter.

Comment: He, I can do that ;-)

Answer (score 6):

## Variable sized tests

Currently, your program uses a text of size 10,000,000 and randomized patterns of size 1,000.  I would have liked to see variations in these sizes, perhaps controlled by command line arguments.

## Boyer Moore

I would have liked to see your program include Boyer Moore, which I consider to be superior to the other algorithms.  Just to see what would happen, I pasted in the java version of Boyer Moore from wikipedia into your program, and here are the results:

> **[WORST CASE OF String.indexOf]
>
> String.indexOf in 4576 milliseconds.
>
> Knuth-Morris-Pratt matcher in 32 milliseconds.
>
> Boyer Moore in 31 milliseconds.
>
> Finite automaton matcher in 47 milliseconds.
>
> Rabin-Karp matcher in 62 milliseconds.
>
> Z matcher in 47 milliseconds.**
>
> **[RANDOM STRINGS]
>
> [SEED: 1446921427388]   String.indexOf in 133 milliseconds.
>
> Knuth-Morris-Pratt matcher in 203 milliseconds.
>
> Boyer Moore in 46 milliseconds.
>
> Finite automaton matcher in 312 milliseconds.
>
> Rabin-Karp matcher in 614 milliseconds.
>
> Z matcher in 361 milliseconds.**

Comment: Boyer Moore implemented and on its way whenever it's (and if) time for a follow up.